# Promise always pending (wrong syntax?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, es6-promise

I'm nearly new to node.js, express and ES6, but trying to get a hang of it. I wrote this code, trying to achieve neat clean ES6-driven functions and promises. But I've got a problem with inherited functions and values, especially next(). So here's my code written so far:

```
    let get_tags = (id) => {
        var id = id;
        return database.connection(
            (connection) => {
                return connection.query(
                    `SELECT
                        t.name
                    FROM
                        wp_terms AS t
                    INNER JOIN
                        wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON tt.term_id = t.term_id
                    INNER JOIN
                        wp_term_relationships AS tr ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
                    WHERE
                        tt.taxonomy IN ('post_tag') AND tr.object_id IN (${id})
                    ORDER BY t.name ASC`
                )
            }
        ).then(
            (rows) => {
                return rows;
            }
        )
    }

    router.get('/:city', (req, res, next) => {
        switch (req.params.city) {
            case 'neanderland':
                var post_type = 'neanderland',
                    title = 'Hauptmeldungen',
                    region = 'Neanderland';
                break;
            case 'wuelfrath':
                var post_type = 'wuelfrath',
                    title = 'Hauptmeldungen',
                    region = 'Wülfrath';
                break;
            case 'mettmann':
                var post_type = 'mettmann',
                    title = 'Hauptmeldungen',
                    region = 'Mettmann';
                break;
            case 'haan':
                var post_type = 'haan',
                    title = 'Hauptmeldungen',
                    region = 'Haan';
                break;
            case 'nevigestoenisheide':
                var post_type = 'neviges-toenisheide',
                    title = 'Hauptmeldungen',
                    region = 'Neviges/Tönisheide';
                break;
        }
        database.connection(
            (connection) => {
                return connection.query(
                    `SELECT
                            p.post_title as title,
                            p.post_author as author,
                            t.name as category,
                            p.ID as id,
                            p.post_date as date,
                            p.post_content as text,
                            p.post_excerpt as excerpt,
                            p.post_status as status,
                            p.post_name as slug_url,
                            pm1.meta_value as hero_thumb_id,
                            pm2.meta_value as hero_thumb_url
                        FROM
                            wp_posts p
                        LEFT JOIN
                            wp_postmeta pm1
                            ON (
                                pm1.post_id = p.id
                                AND pm1.meta_value IS NOT NULL
                                AND pm1.meta_key = "_thumbnail_id"
                            )
                        LEFT JOIN
                            wp_postmeta pm2
                            ON (
                                pm1.meta_value = pm2.post_id
                                AND pm2.meta_key = "_wp_attached_file"
                                AND pm2.meta_value IS NOT NULL
                            )
                        LEFT JOIN
                            wp_term_relationships tr
                            ON (
                                p.ID = tr.object_id
                            )
                        LEFT JOIN
                            wp_term_taxonomy tt
                            ON (
                                tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id
                            )
                        LEFT JOIN
                            wp_terms t
                            ON (
                                tt.term_id = t.term_id
                            )
                        WHERE
                            p.post_status="publish"
                            AND p.post_type="${post_type}"
                            AND tt.taxonomy = "category"
                        GROUP BY p.ID
                        ORDER BY
                            p.post_date DESC
                        LIMIT 100`
                )
            }
        ).then(
            (rows) => {
                var posts = [];
                rows.forEach(
                    (element, index, array) => {
                        var arr = {
                            id : element.id,
                            paywall : element.text.includes('[not-level-free-user]'),
                            date : Date.parse(element.date).format("c"),
                            title : element.title,
                            excerpt : element.excerpt,
                            text : convert_text(element.text),
                            category : convert_category(element.category),
                            region : region,
                            author : convert_author(element.author),
                            slug : element.slug_url,
                            tags : '',
                            media : {
                                heroid : element.hero_thumb_id,
                                heroslug: element.hero_thumb_url
                            }
                        }
                        posts.push(arr);
                    }
                );
                return posts;
            }
        ).then(
            (data) => {
                var arr = [];
                data.forEach(
                    (element, index, array) => {
                        var id = element.id;
                        var item = get_tags(id).then(
                            (result) => {
                                if (result.length >= 1) {
                                    // console.log(result) at this position returns e.g.
                                    // [ RowDataPacket { name: 'Feuerwehr' },
                                    //  RowDataPacket { name: 'Nachwuchs' },
                                    //  RowDataPacket { name: 'Werbung' } ]
                                    return result;
                                }
                            }
                        )
                        // console.log(item) at this position returns
                        // Promise { <pending> }
                        arr.push(item);
                    }
                );
                return arr;
            }
        ).then(
            (data) => {
                res.json(data)
            }
        );

    });
```

Everything works fine, until the second last then(). It returns just empty elements of an array. It seems, that get_tags(id) doesn't save the results for the next then. I did a console log at specific positions, but I can't find the error...I want to save the results of get_tags into the arr variable to return it for the following next() function. You can find the results in the commentations.

Does anyone have an idea what might be going wrong?

Thanks for the help and please be kind...I'm still a rookie! ;-)

Comment: Can you minimise the example code to more concisely illustrate the issue? I don't think we need to see two screens of SQL queries…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the `then` callback that calls `get_tags`. Since `get_tabs` is an asynchronous call, you need to wait for those promises to complete, which is readily done with `Promise.all`.

Trying to keep to your style here:

```
// ...
).then(
    (data) => {
        // Map the data to promises and return a promise that waits for them
        return Promise.all(data.map(
            (element, index, array) => {
                var id = element.id;
                return get_tags(id);
            }
        ));
    }
// Now we use a new `then` to filter the data now we have it
).then(
    (data) => {
        return data.filter(
            (result) => {
                return result.length > 1;
            }
        );
    }
)
// ...
```

---

Side note: This `then` earlier on serves no purpose:

```
).then(
    (rows) => {
        return rows;
    }
)
```

it can just be completely removed (replaced with just that `)` at the end).

A couple of other v. minor notes:

- You don't need `()` around the parameter to an arrow function if there's just one parameter (though of course, you may prefer consistency as a matter of style)
- The concise form of arrow functions is frequently handy (such as the example I showed above filtering the results by `result.length > 1`).

Here's how I'd write the block at the beginning of the answer, FWIW:

```
// ...
)
.then(data => Promise.all(data.map(entry => get_tags(entry.id))))
.then(data => data.filter(result => result.length > 1))
// ...
```

...but it's a matter of style, and to some extent even a matter of what debugger you tend to use as some are better at handling single lines like that than others.

Comment: First of all: so much thanks for your time and all the suggestions. It helps me getting better and to learn how thinks work. I will implement the code and see how it runs. Thumbs up!!!

Answer (score 0):

So I implented your code, it works, of course. But somehow I didn't manage to integrate your code with my array injection. This is my result to get the array filled with the tags in the tag element. Maybe you have a better and shorter solution?

```
.then(
    (data) => {
        var test = data;
        return Promise.all(
            data.map(
                (element, index, array) => {
                    var id = element.id;
                    return get_tags(id);
                }
            )
        ).then(
            data => {
                data.forEach(
                    (element, index, array) => {
                        var tag = [];
                        element.forEach(
                            (element, index, array) => {
                                tag.push(element.name);
                            }
                        );
                        test[index].tags = tag;
                    }
                );
                return test;
            }
        );
    }
)
```

My desired result (with focus on the "tags"):

```
{
    "id": 123456,
    "paywall": true,
    "date": "2017-01-24T15:02:38.000Z",
    "title": "This is a headline",
    "excerpt": "This is an excerpt",
    "text": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.",
    "category": "main",
    "region": "city",
    "author": "John Johnson",
    "slug": "this-is-a-headline",
    "tags": [
        "Tag1",
        "Tag2",
        "Tag3"
    ],
    "media": {
        "heroid": "123456",
        "heroslug": "2017/02/heroimage.jpg"
    }
}
```